# Why are Process Image Names sometimes padded with hex characters?

Tags: .net, debugging, windows-7, clearcase, windows-7-x64

When debugging on my Windows-7 64 bit VM machine I notice that sometimes (perhaps 50%) my exe name has been padded out with strange hex characters:

**8000885a4fe0a0d0des.exe.11048**

other times it is simply plain:

**des.exe**

These are 32 bit .Net4 assemblies built and run on a 64 bit system. As shown in TaskManager.

Anyone know why this is happening?

Edit: This is caused by Clearcase doing strange things on Windows-7. Why it randomly does this or how you can fix it I am not sure.

Comment: Check the full path for a clue.

Comment: This seems to be something to do with Clear Case dynamic views behaving strangely on Windows-7

Comment: Can you please clarify where you are seeing these strange image names? I.e., in Task Manager, some API, etc.

Comment: Yes, as shown in the Image Name column of task manager and the Visual Studio Attach to Process dialog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I'm posting an answer based on the gist of the comments above, so the question stops showing up as "unanswered".)

The problem seems to have been a confusing interaction between [ClearCase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Rational_ClearCase) and the Windows 7 Task Manager. Presumably the different hex-padded filenames represent different versions of the file from ClearCase revision control. Normally ClearCase hides this "nuts and bolts" stuff from the end-user, but in this case Task Manager is not fooled (or at least, only imperfectly fooled).

Comment: Not quite, I think this is a ClearCase bug. Sometimes it gets the right location, but this seems totally random. We are endeavouring to find-out from IBM.